# Loading CSV into PySpark from S3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark

Using PySpark I can load a local CSV just fine using this code:

```
cd ./spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/

./bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 --driver-memory 4G

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('/my/local/folder/input_data.csv').write.save("/my/local/folder/input_data", format="parquet")
```

yet I can't get it to work with a (non-public) CSV stored on S3 because it times out:

```
sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('s3n://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>:<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>@my.bucket/folder/input_data.csv').write.save("/my/local/folder/input_data", format="parquet")


py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out
```

Is this possible and if so, any thoughts what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like the right approach. Can you run a read-only test on a small file in S3 to see if your AWS key/secret are correct and that your path is valid? 

From there, you can diagnose why you are getting the timeout error. Based on what you have here, I suspect your connection string to AWS is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @MylesBaker the actual file is 500MB but I switched it to a 30KB file and it worked fine. Interesting that it's timing out.

Comment: Which version of `com.databricks.spark.csv` are you running? I think this error is introduced by this library.

Comment: You aren't the only one experiencing this issue. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/225) on their github page

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried loading the rdd from plain text ? csv files are quite straightforward to split

```
sc.textFile('/my/local/folder/input_data.csv').map(lambda row:row.split(','))
```